# What is difference in Dirac Notation for probability and Probability Density in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

The Dirac Notation for wave function

$$\langle\psi|\psi\rangle= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^{*}\psi \,dx $$
$$\text{Probability} =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^{*}\psi \,dx $$

But most often it is quoted in books like
$$\text{Probability} =  \vert\langle\psi|\psi\rangle\vert^2 $$

What is this conundrum? I am not able to comprehend.

Comment: Quoted in which books? Which pages?

Comment: All three expressions compute to unity, for a properly normalised wave function. In this sense it is unclear what is asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding this requires understanding the difference between a *wave function* and a *state vector*. The difference between these two is essentially the same as the difference between "vector components" and "vectors" in ordinary vector algebra, in the same respective order. Mathematically, they really *are* the same thing - "vectors" are just elements of general systems called "vector spaces", and the spaces of ordinary vector-algebra vectors and quantum state vectors are both vector spaces.

In particular, in a sense, while an ordinary vector in 3-dimensional, say, space has 3 components, i.e.

$$\mathbf{r}_\mathrm{example} := \left<r_x, r_y, r_z\right>$$

a vector in a quantum state space can, and typically does, have *infinitely many* components - in sense, here it has *uncountably infinitely many* components; the space has an uncountably infinite dimension: effectively, as many "coordinate axes" *as there are real numbers*. Thus, while in the above, we label them with labels "x", "y", and "z", here, we have to *label the components* with a real number or, even, a real-number vector, and hence we have a *function* which returns the component of the vector with a given real-number/real-vectorial "index": this is the *wave function*,

$$\psi(\mathbf{r})$$

which represents the vectorial component indexed by vector $\mathbf{r}$. Effectively, whereas before, you had an x-, y-, and z-axis, you now have, say, a $(0.3, -5.0, \pi)$-axis and a $(5000.3, 10^{-9000}, \Omega_U)$-axis, and a $(35.239\cdots, -4669.1, 10^{10^{10^{100}}})$-axis, and so forth for literally uncountably infinitely many different possibilities each requiring infinite amounts of space to write down exactly when in full generality. The corresponding *vector itself* is denoted

$$|\psi\rangle$$

. The two are related by the following equation:

$$|\psi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \psi(\mathbf{r})|\mathbf{r}\rangle\ dV$$

where $|\mathbf{r}\rangle$ is a *positional basis vector*. Mathematically, it's hard to describe this thing, but the *semantic* denotation is knowledge that a particle is located exactly at the physical spatial position $\mathbf{r}$ (though many quibble over the ontology here). This is analogous to the three vectors $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$, $\hat{\mathbf{y}}$, and $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ in ordinary vector algebra in 3 real dimensions, which allow you to write the $\mathbf{r}_\mathrm{example}$ given at the beginning as

$$\mathbf{r}_\mathrm{example} = r_x \hat{\mathbf{x}} + r_y \hat{\mathbf{y}} + r_z \hat{\mathbf{z}}$$

This is that same formula, only now we have uncountable components and hence (being a bit rough - for lots of really picky reasons the vectors $|\mathbf{r}\rangle$ are actually "bad" and require special treatment to make the above formula actually make sense) need an "uncountable sum", which is provided by an integral. Likewise, just as you can have other *basis vector* sets in 3-dimensional vector algebra, so too can you in infinite-dimensional algebra: and which you're usign depensd on what kind of argument the wave function takes. If it is a function of a position, $\psi(\mathbf{r})$, then that wave function is the position-basis expansion. But you can also have a momentum-basis expansion, with basis vectors $|\mathbf{p}\rangle$ that are tagged by momentum values, and this will give different components.

The notation

$$\left<\phi|\psi\right>$$

represents a *vector inner product*. It is the same thing as the *dot products* you may be familiar with from ordinary vector algebra, only here with the infinite dimensional quantum state vectors instead. The integral representation

$$\left<\phi|\psi\right> = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} [\phi(\mathbf{r})]^{*} \psi(\mathbf{r})\ dV$$

is then how this dot product is described in basis form, and this is *directly* analogous to the usual formula for dot product of 3-space vectors by summing component products.

However, you may also wonder why we say

$$\mathrm{Probability} = |\left<\phi|\psi\right>|^2$$

This is because the actual probability value - here that to obtain $|\phi\rangle$ when querying state $|\psi\rangle$ - is *not* the inner-product itself, which is a *complex* number, as the quantum vectors are *complex* vectors in the sense they have complex, instead of real, components, but rather is given by the expression above.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you got your first equation from. In Dirac notation, 
$\langle x | \psi \rangle = \psi (x)$. And $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle =1$.

Now the probability of finding the particle in location $x\pm \Delta x$ is

$$\int_{x-\Delta x}^{x+\Delta x} |\langle x | \psi \rangle | ^2 dx = \int_{x-\Delta x}^{x+\Delta x} \langle x | \psi \rangle^* \langle x | \psi \rangle dx = \int_{x-\Delta x}^{x+\Delta x} \psi (x)^* \psi (x)dx $$

EDIT: OK, I think I see the source of the confusion. Generally,

$$\langle \phi | \psi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi^* (x) \psi (x) dx$$

This means that the calculation will yield $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle =1$.

Note that the integral is from minus to plus infinity.

The calculation of the probability is in a more limited region. I think that's a key part of your confusion.